# Yii database connection issue

Tags: php, database, apache, yii, oracle10g

## Task

What I need is, to authenticate user based on Oracle DB user system:

- User enters to login page
- Enters username and password
- Application tries to establish connection with given parameters
- If successful, makes this connection persistent over application

I'm using Yii framework.

## What I've done ...

I removed `db` component from `protected/config/main.php` file. Based on [Larry Ulman's blog post](http://goo.gl/YNdWmw) replaced `authenticate` (which located in `protected/components/UserIdentity.php`) with following one

```
public function authenticate()
{
 $dsn='oci:dbname=XE;charset=UTF8';
 $connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,$this->username,$this->password);
 $connection->active=true;
 return $connection->getConnectionStatus();
}
```

Well it didn't establish any connection. BTW in server I tested with oracle client. All works well.

## Questions are

1. I'm not sure if I'm doing it in right manner.
2. How to make established db connection persistent over whole application?

## BTW

My development environment
Oracle DB and Apache 2.2.4 + PHP 5.4 webserver working on Windows Server 2003.

Comment: *Why* on earth did you remove the `db` component?

Comment: 1. You are doing wrong. 2. DB componennt establish connection to database, in config add connection string to this component with all parameters you need and you'll have dbconnection persistenet over all app.

Comment: @ineersa re-read my question. Seems you didn't understand question at all. The main problem is, my connection based on user entered login and pass (user enters login and pass of DATABASE itself. It's not basic authentication when you check auth credentials in some table of db). How can I make persistent db connection without db login and pass? :)

Comment: @MichaelHärtl read comment above

Comment: Why on earth you need this? Writing CPanel? Make cofig with DB connection settings, populate it with user input, merge it with main config.

Comment: @ineersa [facepalm]. you know, not all web applications built on same pattern. Customer need application like I told. I have no choice. And it's easy to speak in words, try to explain on code examples your opinion.

Comment: Your application conection is in config, what you make - is creating custom connection. If you want change app connection - goto Yii::app()->db and change connectionstring with your input data, close connection, setActive then. Should work. About populating config, i did it for changing db and connection depending on subdomain. Can share model to work with configs. https://gist.github.com/ineersa/6089086 . Anyway it was done with env variables from server and configs merge in index.php before app initialize. What other code you need?

Answer (score 1):

It took some time to understand what you want. So basically it's like:

- A user tries to log in with username/password
- To authenticate the user, you check, whether you can establish a DB connection using *that same* username/password as DB credentials
- If the connection could be opened, the user should have a `db` component available, that uses this same connection credentials throughout the user session

Your approach to create a custom `UserIdentity` is right. They are meant for doing the authentication. I'm not sure, why your code there fails, but you're on the right track. Maybe `getConnectionStatus()` does not work right for Oracle. You could try to execute another simple SQL command for a test.

If you've managed to test for a successful connection, you should store the `username` and `password` in the user session, e.g.

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('__db_username',$this->username);
Yii::app()->user->setState('__db_password',$this->password);
```

Now to have the `db` component available after login is a bit tricky. You can take different approaches. I'll describe two:

#### 1. Create a custom CDbConnection

```
class DynamicDbConnection extends CDbConnection
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->username = Yii::app()->user->getState('__db_username');
        $this->password = Yii::app()->user->getState('__db_password');

        if(!$this->username || !$this->password) {
            throw new CException('No username/password available! User not logged in?');
        }
        parent::init();
     }
}
```

Now you can configure this as `db` component in your `main.php` *without* username and password, of course:

```
'components' => array(
    'db' => array(
        'class' => 'DynamicDbConnection',
        'connectionString' =>'oci:dbname=XE;charset=UTF8',
    ),
 ),
```

#### 2. Adding a CDbConnection from Controller::init()

You could add a `db` component from your base controllers `init()` method:

```
class Controller extends CController
{
    public function init()
    {
        $username = Yii::app()->user->getState('__db_username');
        $password = Yii::app()->user->getState('__db_password');

        if($username && $password) {
            Yii::app()->setComponent('db', array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
            ));
        }
        parent::init();
   }
```

You also still need a base `db` component configuration in your `main.php` for this.

Both approaches may need a little tweaking as i've not tested this. But you should get the basic idea.